# How to determine which button is pressed on iOS devices using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ios

I am intercepting form submissions so that I can reroute them in my single page app (I'm not using a framework, just plain Javascript). Some of my code has multiple buttons with the same name. The following code works on Chrome/Desktop, but does not work on iOS. Specifically, in the following sample code, using document.activeElement doesn't work on iOS. How can I determine which button was pressed on iOS so that I only pass the correct button name/value?

Ideally, the solution would not involve modifying the existing form (other than the 'submit' event listener).

```
<html>
<body>
  <span id="app">
    <form method="POST" action="/test">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="123">
      <input name="email" id="email" class="form-control" type="text">
      <button name="action" value="one">One</button>
      <button name="action" value="two">Two</button>
      <button name="action" value="three">Three</button>
      <button name="action" value="four">Four</button>      
    </form>
  </span>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("app").addEventListener("submit", myfunc);

    function myfunc(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      let action = e.target.getAttribute("action");
      console.log("action:", action);
      let ae = document.activeElement;
      console.log("ae:", ae);

      // On iOS btnname and btnval are null. They should be the name
      // and value of the button that did the form submittion.
      let btnname = ae.getAttribute('name');
      let btnval = ae.getAttribute('value');
      console.log("btnname:", btnname);
      console.log("btnval:", btnval);

      let elements = e.target.elements;
      for (i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        let ele = elements[i];
        if (ele.type == "submit") {
          if (btnval == undefined) {
              console.log("skipping:", ele.value)
              continue;
          }
          if (ele.name == btnname) {
            if (ele.value != btnval || btnval == undefined) {
              console.log("skipping:", ele.value)
              continue;
            }
            console.log("found pressed button: ", btnval)
          }
        }
        console.log("submitting: ", ele.name)
        console.log("submitting: ", ele.value)
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with involves adding a `click` event handler. `click` handlers always fire before `submit` event handlers. With the `click` event handler, I record the name and value of the button that was clicked. Then, I can use those in the `submit` handler, ignoring all elements of type `submit`. Here is sample code, that also handles check boxes and radio buttons.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<body>
  <span id="app">
    <form method="POST" action="/test">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="123">
      <input name="email" id="email" class="form-control" type="text">
      <button name="action" value="one">One</button>
      <button name="action" value="two">Two</button>
      <button name="action" value="three">Three</button>
      <button name="action" value="four">Four</button>      
      <input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="checkvalue1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="check2" value="checkvalue2" checked>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio1">
      <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio2" checked>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio3">
      <a href="#">click me!</a>
    </form>
  </span>
  <script>
    var submitName;
    var submitValue;
    // click events fire before submit events
    document.getElementById("app").addEventListener("submit", myfunc);
    document.getElementById("app").addEventListener("click", setSubmit);

    function myfunc(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      let action = e.target.getAttribute("action");
      console.log("action:", action);
      let elements = e.target.elements;
      if (submitName != "") {
        console.log("submitting: ", submitName)
        console.log("submitting: ", submitValue)
      }
      for (i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        let ele = elements[i];
        if (ele.type == "submit") {
        } else if (ele.type == "checkbox" || ele.type == "radio") {
          if (ele.checked == false) {
            continue
          }
        }
        console.log("submitting: ", ele.name)
        console.log("submitting: ", ele.value)
      }
    }
    function setSubmit(e)
    {
      console.log("type:", e.target.type);
      if (e.target.type != "submit") {
        return;
      }
      // record the name/value of the button that was pressed
      submitName = e.target.name;
      submitValue = e.target.value;
    }

  </script>
</body>
```